Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Which calling convention to use for EAX/EDX in IDA
Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)




How to use sysenter under Linux?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)




Are those code snippets and file paths in a C++ binary some sort of standard debug information?
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)




Deal with obfuscated assembly
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)




Inserting resources.properties file into an APK - language compatibility
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)




What does this memory pattern pointing from the thread-local storage mean?
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)




Storing barcodes as ASCII
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)




Moving from Windows to Linux for Malware analysis. What should I consider?
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)




Some programs have always same addressing and some different
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)




How to find file compression or obfuscation type
Net Score: -3 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)



